# Palm rotation in LeapJS

Tags: rotation, leap-motion

I wonder how could I get the correct palm rotation angle (along Y-axis) from Leap Motion (I'm using the latest [LeapJS API](http://js.leapmotion.com/api_guide))?

I have tried both `rotationAngle(sinceFrame)` method and the `frame._rotation`. However, the `rotationAngle()` returns a very small value close to `0`, which seems to be the rotation angle calculated based on the current frame (how to define the `sinceFrame` in `Leap.loop(function(frame)){}`, as it seems only records data from current frame).

And the `frame._rotation` returns a 3*3 matrix (which I've no idea about what is it, as it's not included in the API documentation). Therefore, I wonder if there's any way to get the correct rotation angle of Y-axis from these methods?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the leap.js library includes a roll() function as a member of the Hand object. (It also has pitch() and yaw(), if roll() isn't all you want.) The roll() function is defined as:

```
Hand.prototype.roll = function() {
  return Math.atan2(this.palmNormal[0], -this.palmNormal[1]);
}
```

As an aside, since you don't need to use rotationAngle() to get the current palm angles, the rotationAngle() function gives you the rotation that has occurred between two frames. For sinceFrame, you can either store a reference to the starting frame or get a past frame from the history buffer maintained by the Controller object. Although the Leap.loop() function doesn't give you access to its Controller object directly, you should be able to create your own. Note that frame._rotation is an internal variable that is used in the calculation of the transformations between two frames. It isn't much use on its own.